# Prevent sql injection using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working with "Rest API's/web services" in codeigniter,And i want to make Api secure
So for this purpose i am using following query (for example)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($title).")";
```

I want to know that above way is enough for prevent sql injection using codeigniter or there should be something more ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Doesnt Codeigniters built in database class already handle that for you?

Comment: you should use codeigniter's Querybulider, first read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is perfectly solvable with Codeigniters query builder.
In your case it would look like

```
$arrData = [
    'title' => $title
];

$this->db->insert('table', $arrData);
```

As mentioned Codeigniter comes with a built in query builder. I strongly suggest to use it because it makes your life much easier. If you use it you are protected against sql injections.

> Take a look at their documentation and study it carefully - [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) is the link.

Comment: it means i dont need to use like any technique or any code/function for prevent sql injection , Codeigniter itself preventing sql injection, i have to write simple insert query ( like as you mentioned ) ??

Comment: yes - thats it - as long as you use the query builder properly - you are protected against sql injections.

Comment: my last question is " is codeigniter by default including query builder ?" and i have to write simple insert , update or delete query ....right ?

Comment: you have to set in your `database.php` under `application/config/` the variable `$query_builder = true;`. After that you can use your models.

Comment: in my side, its already true, it means sql preventing in my side already, am i right sir ?